# Poisson Processes - Voters problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

here's what I tried after some help: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbVhO.png)

> Voters for candidate A and candidate B arrive at a polling station as per a Poisson process with equal probability. The rate of arrival of voters is 100 voters per hour. Therefore, you can assume that the arrival of voters for candidate A and of voters for candidate B are two independent Poisson processes, each having a rate 50 voters per hour. If 1000 voters arrive in 10 hours, compute the probability that m of them are for candidate A. Hint: Use independence of two processes.

Can anyone please tell me how to go about this question? I have tried solving it like this: $m+B= 1000$, where B = number of voters for candidate B, so: $((m+B)^{1000}\dfrac{e^{(-m+B)}}{1000!}$ Now i am not sure how to find $m$ and $B$. Could anyone please help me? What am I missing? I used sum of independent Poisson random variables.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The title of the question should have something to do with the specific question itself. Imagine what would happen if everyone who wanted to know how to solve a question would use the title “can anyone please tell me how to go about this question?”.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(\text{$m$ voted for $B$ } \mid \text{ $1000$ voters in $10$ hrs})
= \frac{P(\text{$1000$ voters in $10$ hrs, $m$ voted for $B$})}{P(\text{$1000$ voters in $10$ hrs})}.$$

---

The denominator is straightforward to compute (the number of voters in $10$ hours is $\text{Poisson}(100 \cdot 10)$, compute the probability that this equals $1000$).

---

The numerator is equivalent to
$$P(\text{in 10 hrs, $m$ voted for $B$, $1000-m$ voted for $A$}).$$
Using independence, this is equal to
$$P(\text{in 10 hrs, $m$ voted for $B$}) \cdot P(\text{in $10$ hrs, $1000-m$ voted for $A$}).$$
Finally, use the fact that each candidate's voters form a Poisson process with rate $50$ voters/hour to compute each term here.

---

After you put all the pieces together and perform some cancellations, you should recover something that looks like the probability of getting $m$ heads in $1000$ coin flips. This formalizes the [nice property](https://www.randomservices.org/random/poisson/Splitting.html) that any given voter in the combined process is equally likely to be a supporter of $A$ as they are to be a supporter of $B$.

---

More details:

The denominator is $e^{-1000} \frac{1000^{1000}}{1000!}$.

The arrivals of voters for $B$ form a Poisson process with rate 50 voters/hour. Therefore,
the number of voters for $B$ in a $10$-hour period is Poisson with mean $50 \cdot 10 = 500$, so
$$P(\text{in 10 hrs, $m$ voted for $B$}) = e^{-500} \frac{500^m}{m!}.$$
The other term in the numerator is $e^{-500} \frac{500^{1000-m}}{(1000-m)!}$.

Comment: thanks, I have done till the numerator part but im not sure how to use rate of 50 because now my numerator is in terms of m and there's no way i could plug 50 in it. Would it be possible for you to please elaborate on this: "Finally, use the fact that each candidate's voters form a Poisson process with rate 50 voters/hour to compute each term here."

Comment: @user1066413 $P(\text{in $10$ hrs, $m$ voted for $B$}) = e^{-500} 500^m/m!$.

Comment: im sorry if i sound dumb but i am still unable to understand how that information helps. I have updated what I have done so far in the question. would it be possible for u to pls have a look at it?

Comment: @user1066413 You are using the rate for the combined process rather than the rate for the smaller process consisting of only voters for B (or for A). Added more details to my answer.

Comment: Oh okay, it makes sense now. I got (1/2)^1000 times some stuff. So, yes my probability is 1/2 as you mentioned. Thank you so muchhhh for helping me out!